# Minimum number of integer-sided squares needed to tile an $m$ by $n$ rectangle.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, packing-problem, tiling, extremal-combinatorics

Let $T(m,n)$ for integers $m,n$ be the least number of integer-sided squares needed to tile an $m\times n$ rectangle. Clearly $T(kx,ky)\leq T(x,y)$. Are there integers $x,y,k\gt 1$, such that $T(kx,ky)<T(x,y)$?

Comment: For some references and perhaps some computational ideas: http://oeis.org/A219158

Comment: Of course not.  (Waves hands and ducks)  Maybe you can use some of the ideas in [Fourteen proofs of a result about tiling a rectangle-Wagon](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Wagon601-617.pdf) to prove this.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/113899/minimum-number-of-integer-sided-squares-needed-to-tile-an-m-times-n-rectangle

Comment: Solutions up to 300×300 can be seen at [Minimally Squared Rectangles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MinimallySquaredRectangles/) and  [int-e.eu](http://int-e.eu/~bf3/squares/view.html#13,11). No counterexamples found yet.

Answer (score 4):

$T(m,n)$ is tabulated at the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A219158). Also, several references are given:

Richard J. Kenyon, Tiling a rectangle with the fewest squares, Combin. Theory Ser. A 76 (1996), no. 2, 272-291.

Mark Walters, Rectangles as sums of squares, Discrete Math. 309 (2009), no. 9, 2913-2921.

Bertram Felgenhauer, [Tiling rectangles by minimal number of squares](http://int-e.cohomology.org/~bf3/haskell/Young.hs).

Maybe you could have a look at those, to see whether your question is considered (and, if it is, you could then report back).

Comment: No luck there..

Answer (score 4):

I've posted a 4944 possible counterexamples at [Possible Counterexamples to the Minimal Squaring Conjecture](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PossibleCounterexamplesToTheMinimalSquaringConjecture/). Odds are at least one of these is a valid counterexample.

Data and verified pictures up to 388 at [Minimally Squared Rectangles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MinimallySquaredRectangles/)

[image: possible counterexample]

Other information at [tiling a rectangle with the smallest number of squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116382/tiling-a-rectangle-with-the-smallest-number-of-squares)

According to my notes there, my minimal possible counterexample is currently

[image]

Comment: It seems that $81 \times 71$ only needs $10$ squares so the $12$ square tiling for the larger rectangle is not optimal. This [link](http://oeis.org/A219158/b219158.txt) lists the minimal numbers for the tilings. $81 \times 71$ is entry $3311$. The list is a continuation of [A219158](http://oeis.org/A219158).

Comment: Yes, @EuYu. Rectangle $71 \times 81$ requires $10$ squares only. Edges (for example): $38$ (left-up), $43$(right-up), $33$(left-bottom), $28$(right-bottom), $20$(bottom), $8$, $8$, $5$, $4$ and $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Bouwkamp code of two simple perfect squared rectangles:

- 13: 304x274 (141,78,85)(71,7)(92)(133,8)(51,28)(23,97)(74);
- 15: 152x137 (83,69)(31,38)(54,29)(16,15)(8,30)(25,4)(1,22)(21).

There is no lower-order simple squared rectangle of either size, but there might be compound ones. If not then T(304,274) = 13, T(152,137) = 15, and T(304,274) < T(152,137).

Comment: There is no restriction to distinct squares.

Comment: The $152 \times 137$ rectangle can be subdivided into 12 squares with integer side lengths. http://pictat.com/show.php?i=/2012/11/29/43292squaredrec.png